# Java(Jacob) + Russian language

Tags: java, wmi, jacob

I've been writing a program on Java with library jacob, which help to work with wmi. and faced with such a problem, the team does not work in Cyrillic.

```
   String userName = Dispatch.get(dItem2, "Name").getString();
   String objUser = "WinNT://IUMAG/" + userName + ",user";
   Dispatch dServ2 = new Dispatch(objUser);
```

If the username is written in Russian, then there is an error, and if English, then everything is fine
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check you encoding... UTF-8 supports does Cyrilic (and whatever other text you got). Windows default is CP1251 /cp1252?... You can try to translate the text to byte [] , then back to `new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")` when you print this, you should see Cyrillic

Comment: I tried, did not work :(

Comment: Ok... First, what is the error? And what are the characters you get? (Sorry for the text, I don't know what the following means) `Кириллон алфавит` or `ÐÐ¸ÑÐ¸Ð»Ð»Ð¾Ð½ Ð°Ð»ÑÐ°Ð²Ð¸Ñ`? Or do you get the `�` Unicode unknown character? (translated what I wrote, seems not to be offensive, nice)

Comment: > Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException:    Can't find moniker
 at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
 at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
 at javaapplication20.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:43)
Java Result: 1
I use Russian language, example: "Администратор"

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer goes to (for English speakers) from http://www.sql.ru/forum/1167615/java-jacob-rabota-s-kirillicey:

> Macro A2W converts data from ANSI encoding in Windows Wide char. Hence
>   the conclusion, the input line should contain data in ANSI encoding
>   Windows (probably in 1251), but not in UTF8 (as is customary in Java).
>   Authors JACOB course little monsters that have not made ​​the
>   conversion from UTF8 (adopted in Java) in Wide char. But I think the
>   national names in COM not so common. including I would like to try a
>   hand in Java to convert a string of UTF in 1251. It is clear that work
>   is only on Windows, where as ANSI encoding is 1251, ie Default
>   characterset = Russian

Originally in Russian:

> Макрос A2W преобразует данные из ANSI кодировки Windows в Wide char.
>   Отсюда вывод, входные строка должна содержать данные в ANSI кодировки
>   Windows (скорее всего 1251), а НЕ в UTF8 (как принято в Java).
>
> Авторы JACOB конечно немного уроды, что НЕ сделали преобразование из
>   UTF8 (принятой в Java) в Wide char. Но, думаю, национальные имена в
>   COM не так часто встречаются.
>
> Т.ч. я бы попробывал просто руками в Java преобразовать строку из UTF
>   в 1251. Понятное дело, что работать будет только на Windows, где в
>   качестве ANSI кодировки стоит 1251, т.е. Default characterset =
>   Russian.

So, Java, by default, uses UTF-8, but Windows, hence the Jakob, uses cp1251. So convert the username, if `Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC` then convert from `UTF-8` to `cp1251`.

Disclaimer, I'm unsure how good the Google translators translated the page...

Update, using UnicodeBlock to determine character type, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html for more information on UnicodeBlocks

```
//XXX over simplification, for it can also be CJK (Chinese Japanese Korean) or other...

public String hasCyrillicCharacters(final String text){
    final char[] cc = text.toCharArray();
    for (char c : cc) {
        if (UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC == UnicodeBlock.of(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC What it? Tell me how to use it, please?

Comment: See last part of updated answer... If you wish to use other character sets (note I'm unsure about the cp1251 mapping!) you can test other UnicodeBlock

Comment: I assume you have tried searching in Russian? My Russian is poor, at best. But this problem will most probably be document (if more than the one I proposed) in Russian, or Chinese maybe?

Comment: @AsmaRod btw (maybe I assumed incorrectly) but you might try in the Russian StackOverFlow http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ if they speak the language, and code... problems (good ones :) )

Comment: One more question, please. Did I change utf to windows-125, right?

Comment: String objUser = "WinNT://IUMAG/Администратор,user";
                        String objUser2 = new String(objUser.getBytes("utf-8"),"cp1251");

Comment: I think: String objUser3 = new String(objUser.getBytes("utf-8"), "Windows-1252"); -> WinNT://IUMAG/Ð�Ð´Ð¼Ð¸Ð½Ð¸Ñ�Ñ‚Ñ€Ð°Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€,user instead of cp1251 -> WinNT://IUMAG/РђРґРјРёРЅРёСЃС‚СЂР°С‚РѕСЂ,user